# Fetch field Details for a login use in Django REST Framework with foreignkeyfield Relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add Value into InstantInvestment Model in Django REST Framework which is working. but, only want to show the shipping that is specifically for the login user in. which means, the present situation is giving all the shipping not for this user.

models.py

```
class Shipping(models.Model):
    investor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='shipping', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    beneficiary = models.CharField("Beneficiary Name", max_length=150)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name="bank", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
    address = models.TextField("Shipping Adresss")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.beneficiary

    class Meta:
        
        verbose_name = 'Shipping'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Shippings'


class InstantInvestment(models.Model):
   
    
    investor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='instantivestment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    investment = models.FloatField("Investment in dollar")
    rate = models.FloatField("Exchange Rate")
    transferable = models.FloatField("Money Transferable")
    conversion = models.FloatField("Rate in Naira")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='instant_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, related_name='shipping', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    done = models.BooleanField("Completed Transaction", default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.investor.get_full_name()} - Transaction Code: {self.ref_code}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'InstantInvestment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'InstantInvestments'
```

serializers.py

```
class ShippingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    
    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
        fields = ('beneficiary', 'bank', 'account', 'address') 



class QucikPaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    

    class Meta:
        model = InstantInvestment
        fields = ('url', 'id','investment', 'rate', 'transferable', 'conversion', 'product', 'shipping')
```

views.py

```
class QuickPaymentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = InstantInvestment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QucikPaymentSerializer

    permission_classes = [ permissions.IsAuthenticated ]
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InstantInvestment.objects.filter(investor=self.request.user, done=False) 

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(investor=self.request.user)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `shipping__investor=self.request.user` in your ModelViewSet?

Comment: what is the relation between investor of InstantInvestment and investor of Shipping?

Comment: shipping = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, related_name='shipping', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: how should I place it - shipping__investor=self.request.user

Comment: In your `def get_queryset(self):`

Comment: I already have def get_queryset(self):
        return InstantInvestment.objects.filter(investor=self.request.user, done=False) in my ModelViewSet

Comment: yes, and I told you to try adding `shipping__investor=self.request.user` to that queryset filter...?

Comment: How do I join both query is the issue

Comment: Then, not in view but in create.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. What I suggested  `def get_queryset(self):
return InstantInvestment.objects.filter(investor=self.request.user, done=False)` right here, add `shipping__investor=self.request.user` inside that queryset filter(). That should be pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the query set attribute in your viewset class

```
class QuickPaymentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QucikPaymentSerializer
    permission_classes = [ permissions.IsAuthenticated ]
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InstantInvestment.objects.filter(investor=self.request.user, done=False) 

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(investor=self.request.user)
```

to make it work you need to specify the basename key word argument when you register your viewset class with router.

```
router.register(r'quickpayment/' , QuickPaymentView , basename='InstantInvestment')
```

Comment: I have no issue with this. In creating a new quickPaymentView, I need the shipping that belong to the present user. The present situation now is showing all shipping in the database

Comment: Are you mentioning the HTML form that you showed the question?

Comment: Yes... I need the shipping to show the only entering from the user

Answer (score 0):

If you want do so you need to write a html  separately. I think that you showed in your question is rest frameworks ui to test the api. That UI can't determine the User before you send the request.